# Angular 6 + Kendo UI - Grid data not displaying correctly

Tags: angular, angular6, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the **Kendo** Grid to display data from filtered requests. My template is only displaying the same line (first line of data) repeatedly instead of iterating the data correctly. 
The correct number of the data row is displayed vertically but every time it is the same data as it does not iterate properly. (I tried putting the *ngFor in the `ng-template` of `kendoGridCellTemplate` as well.)
When I play around with my code, for example, if I put my *ngFor in a `ngContainer`, I can see the code can be iterated but horizontally creating a full column each time a X number of time.

What am I doing wrong? How should I proceed to solve this issue?

Example >>where myRequests = Request[] >>

```
 <kendo-grid [data]="myRequests">
    <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Name" width="100px">
      <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
        <div>Name</div>
      </ng-template>
      <div *ngFor="let request of myRequests>
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate field="name" let-dataItem>
          {{ name(request) }}
        </ng-template>
      </div>
    </kendo-grid-column>
 </kendo-grid>
```

Comment: Can you share what this `name(request)` function is doing?

Comment: `name(request: Request): string {
    if (request.type === 'edit-domain') {
      return 'Hierarchy';
    }
    return request.data.find(d => d.key === 'Name').value;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example you provided, you're only declaring ONE kendo grid column for the `field="name"` of our datasource. Then iterating over your `myRequests` to generate multiple templates. But also you're passing `myRequests` as the DataSource to the Grid.

I believe `kendo-grid-column` accepts only one `kendoGridCellTemplate` content child.

Try this instead

```
  <kendo-grid [data]="myRequests">
    <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Name" width="100px">
      <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
        <div>Name</div>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate field="name" let-dataItem>
        <!-- Define your template here -->
        <!-- Your intent of looping and calling a function is unclear from the question -->
        <!-- Kendo will iterate over `myRequests` and pass each request into the `dataItem` template variable -->
        {{ name(dataItem) }}
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
 </kendo-grid>
```